# Creating a binary vector with specific proportion of ones

Tags: r, binary-data, proportion

I want to generate a binary vector of size $n=20$ with a proportion of ones equal to $\frac {3}{20}$

```
binary_vector <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.15)
```

But why this does not always give a fixed proportion of 0.15 :

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 #  5%
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 #  0%
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 # 15%
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 # 20%
```

Comment: Why would it, it is a random variable after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Generate binary vector with the specified proportion of ones
binary_vector <- sample(c(rep(1, round(sample_size * proportion_of_ones)),
                          rep(0, round(sample_size * (1 - proportion_of_ones)))), 
                        size = sample_size, replace = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fixed proportion of ones, the simplest way would be to start with three ones and 17 zeros, and then permute this randomly:

```
> foo <- c(rep(1,3),rep(0,17))
> sample(foo,length(foo))
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
> sample(foo,length(foo))
 [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
> sample(foo,length(foo))
 [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: `sample(foo)` does a permutation of the whole of `foo`